# performing calculations with values in xml CLOB which has identical tags using sql

Tags: sql, xml, xml-parsing

I've got a table (event_archive) and one of the columns(event_xml) has CLOB data in xml format as below. Is there a way to use SQL to summate the values of the "xx" tag? Please help as i'm completely baffled. Even simply extracting the values is a problem as there are 2 "xx" tags within the same root. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<event type="CALCULATION">
    <source_id>INTERNAL</source_id>
    <source_participant/>
    <source_role/>
    <source_start_pos>1</source_start_pos>
    <destination_participant/>
    <destination_role/>
    <event_id>123456</event_id>
    <payload>
        <cash_point reference="abc12345">
            <adv_start>20120907</adv_start>
            <adv_end>20120909</adv_end>
            <conf>1234</conf>
            <profile>3</profile>
            <group>A</group>
            <patterns>
                <pattern id="00112">
                   <xx>143554.1</xx>
                   <yyy>96281.6</yyy>
                   <adv>875</adv>
                </pattern>
                <pattern id="00120">
                   <xx>227606.1</xx>
                   <yyy>97539.8</yyy>
                   <adv>18181</adv>
                </pattern>
             </patterns>
         </cash_point>
</payload>
</event>
```

Comment: Which database vendor (Oracle, SQL Server, etc.) and version?  This should be possible, but the exact syntax will depend on the specific vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Different databases handle XML differently. There's no standard way of dealing with XML payloads via raw, standard SQL. So you'll need to look at your actual DB implementation to find out what support they have.

Comment: @Cheran Shunmugavel. Sorry I took a while to reply. Had to wait 'til I got back to the office for the info. Anyway, I'm trying to use Oracle's SQL Developer. It turns out the version is quite old:

Comment: @Cheran Shunmugavel:Anyway, I'm trying to use Oracle's SQL Developer Version 1.5.4. Quite old version, but the only other alternative I have for the moment is Oracle SQL*Plus, Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition, Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production with the Partitioning, OLAP and Data mining Options. Hope this narrows things down sufficiently. Thanks

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I'm not sure I understand payloads that well. We've got Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition, but I don't know exactly how it uses payloads. Any pointers will be greatly appreaciated. Thanks.